# Vee-Validate custom errror component with scopes

Tags: vuejs2, vee-validate

I wanted to create a custom component to use Vee-Validate scopes to display the error.

Currently for the forms with the scope i am doing in a following ways.

**Submit Method:**

```
   methods: {
      onSubmit(scope) {
        console.log(this.$validator)
        this.$validator.validateAll().then((result) => {
          if (result) {
            alert('Form Submitted!');
          }
        });
      }
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<label>Name</label>

<input v-model="form_fields.name" data-vv-as="Partner name" data-vv-name="PartnerName" v-validate="'required'" :class="{'input': true, 'is-danger': errors.has('form-partner.PartnerName') }" type="text" class="form-control">

<div v-show="errors.has('form-partner.PartnerName')" class="help is-danger text-red">{{ errors.first('form-partner.PartnerName') }}</div>
```

which means i have to repeat `errors.has('form-partner.PartnerName')` multiple times, all over the forms.

I wanted to simplified as below.

```
<error-form :status="errors" :css-class="'is-danger'" label="Company Name" field="name">
    <b-form-input v-validate="'required'" class="form-control" v-model="form_fields.name" name="name" data-vv-as="Company Name"
      type="text" />
</error-form>
```

[Similar to the implementation from here!](https://github.com/vanderleisilva/vue-bootstrap-validate) but this is not working with the scopes.

I wanted to have the validation done with `scopes`. I will pass the scopes to the `error-form` as a prop like shown below.

```
///scope here
<error-form :status="errors" :scope='form-registraion' :css-class="'is-danger'" label="Company Name" field="name">
```

So, how i can check on my `error-form` component with the scopes? scopes could be mandatory or required.